# sed: backslash-apostrophe pattern replacement

Tags: sed, escaping

I have a need to globally replace the pattern `\'` with `\ '` (`\[space]'`) in a file.

I am trying the following sed command:

```
sed 's/\\\'/\\ \'/g' »In-file« > »Out-file«
```

but I am getting the following error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unterminated `s' command

What is the right way to invoke sed in this case?

Comment: `sed "s/\\\'/\\\ '/g"`

Comment: It works for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\\'\''/\\ '\''/g' fileIn > fileOut
```

Or:

```
sed "s/\\\'/\\\ '/g" fileIn > fileOut
```

The first solution punches a hole into the shell and retrieves a quoted single quote, whereas the second surrounds the sed script by double quotes. In both cases back slashes need to be quoted by a back slash.